# Why does GetKeyState work properly when it is on the stack, but when it is on the heap it causes a silent exit?

Tags: c++, windows

I might be missing something obvious, and forgive me if I am.

Anyways, I have a class `Keys` which has method `SPrintScreen` as follows:

```
class Keys{
    uint32_t sentQM;

    // create array to be passed to SendInput function
    INPUT printscreen[2];

    // set both types to keyboard events
    printscreen[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    printscreen[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    // assign printscreen key
    printscreen[0].ki.wVk = VK_SNAPSHOT;
    printscreen[1].ki.wVk = VK_SNAPSHOT;

    // add key up flag to second input
    printscreen[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    void SPrintScreen(){
        sentQM = SendInput(2, printscreen, sizeof(INPUT));
        if (sentQM != ARRAYSIZE(printscreen)){
            std::cout << "could not simulate print screen" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

When I create the `Keys` object on the stack (`Keys keys;`) then call `SPrintScreen` ( keys.SPrintScreen() ), things work as expected, and the pressing of the print screen key is simulated and the program can continue running.

However when I create the `Keys` object on the heap (`Keys* keys;`), and call `SPrintScreen` ( keys->SPrintScreen() )the program just silently exits without any indication of why, not even a message in the console.

How is this working only sometimes?

Comment: Show the code, how exactly you're _creating `Keys` on the heap_. [Edit] your question accordingly please!

Comment: "*However when I create the Keys object on the heap (Keys* keys;)*" That creates a pointer. It doesn't create anything on the heap.

Comment: I may have not been specific enough with the wording, I realise the asterisk makes a pointer but I was led to believe that it is a pointer to where the object is created on the heap? Should I say allocated on the heap instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Keys* keys;
```

does not create a Keys object. It creates a pointer to a keys object. In order do something you have to do 2 more things

- create a Keys objects
- point `keys` at it

Like this

```
Keys *keyObj = new Keys();
keys = keyObj;
```

obviously you would actually do

```
Keys *keys = new Keys();
```

This makes a Keys object on the heap. Alternatively, you could have one on the stack

```
Keys mykeys;
Keys *keys = &mykeys;
```

Which works for you depends on what you are trying to do. Also try not to have naked pointers for heap objects, use shared_ptr or unique_ptr